# Can't install PyQT5 on Mac with pip3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyqt5

I tried to install PyQt5 on Mac (10.12.4 sierra) with pip3 but so far, no success. I saw several answers here on SO, but non helped me. After some different attempts I deleted python3 completely and did a fresh install (downloaded the installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).

After python3 was working again, I ran `pip3 install PyQt5`, which finished successfully, but it is still not working.

I'm testing with this script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QTWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

and the error message is always

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyTestGui.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QTWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QTWidgets'
```

I assume, that I either forgot something, or that my old python installation is not fully removed and still in the way...

**Edit:**
1) Before, I tried the installation via Homebrew, but I had the same problem.
2) Here my pip3 list:

```
pip (9.0.1)
PyQt5 (5.8.2)
setuptools (28.8.0)
sip (4.19.2)
```

3) Is there any way to test intermediate steps to understand better, at which step the installation is failing?

Comment: What does `pip3 freeze` show?

Comment: I get `PyQt5==5.8.2
sip==4.19.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that the correct package is `PyQt5.QtWidgets` and not `PyQt5.QTWidgets`.

This can be seen by doing a `help(PyQt5)` after importing it.